# When to show a dropdown window in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I'm getting the following error when trying to `autocompleteTextView.showDropDown()`:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I've tried to do this in various `Fragment` lifecycle methods. This error always pops up.

Where do I call methods that display additional windows in a fragment?

**EDIT:**

```
@BindView(R.id.acService) AutoCompleteTextView autocompleteSTextView;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context)
{
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();
    context = null;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    initialize();
    loadSkillsData();
    super.onResume();
}

private void initialize()
{
    util = new Util(context);
    requestService = new RequestService();
    requestService.setServerUserId(getUser().getServerUserId());
    geoDataClient = Places.getGeoDataClient(context);

    autocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(context, geoDataClient, BOUNDS_WORLD, null);
    autocompleteTextView.setAdapter(autocompleteAdapter);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    autocompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            if(hasFocus)
            {
                autocompleteService.showDropDown();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here's how the fragment is loaded in the `Activity`. I'm using the MaterialNavigationDrawer:

```
private void replaceWithFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, fragment).commit();
    navigationDrawer.closeDrawer();
}
```

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: Looks like it's not identifying your Activity in which this Fragment is situated.

Comment: @TheWanderer added.

Comment: Is that code from the Activity or the Fragment?

Comment: @TheWanderer From the fragment. The final bit is from the activity.

Comment: Try putting `super.onResume()` at the beginning of `onResume()`. Also, I think you need to run `initialize()` from `onAttach()` instead.

Comment: @TheWanderer I've already tried calling super at the start. Didn't work. Same error.

Comment: How about moving the `initialize()` method call?

Comment: @TheWanderer won't work. Can't touch views in onAttach from what I understand.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I confused with on `onAttachedToWindow()`.

Comment: Try using `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: @TheWanderer just tried. Same error. I've been stuck here for quite some time :)

Comment: Can you post your complete code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179638/discussion-between-asim-and-thewanderer).

Comment: @TheWanderer I've posted a link to my code in the chat.

Comment: @TheWanderer added the activity code in the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onFocusChange()` can be called before anything is actually visible.

Change

```
if(hasFocus)
{
    autocompleteService.showDropDown();
}
```

to

```
if(hasFocus && isVisible())
{
    autocompleteService.showDropDown();
}
```

This will make sure the fragment is actually showing and added to a Window before you try to show the dropdown.